# Hopf invariant of $f\colon S^{11}\to S^6$ is even

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $f\colon S^{11}\to S^6$ be a smooth map, it Hopf invariant is defined as
$$
H(f)=\int_{S^{11}}\varphi\wedge\mathrm{d}\varphi
$$
where $\varphi$ is a $5$-form such that $\mathrm{d}\varphi=f^*\alpha$, and $\alpha$ is a closed $6$-form such that $\int_{S^6}\alpha=1$

Now I'm going to show $H(f)$ must be even, here is my proof:

Let $\rho$ denote the antipodal map on $S^{11}$, that is $x\mapsto-x$, set
$$
\beta=\frac12(\rho^*\varphi-\varphi)
$$
then $\varphi+\beta$ is $\rho^*$-invariant, thus there exists a $5$-form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{RP}^{11}$ such that $\varphi+\beta=\pi^*\omega$, where $\pi\colon S^{11}\to\mathbb{RP}^{11}$ is canonical projection. Furthermore, since $\rho$ is homotopic to $\operatorname{id}_{S^{11}}$, then $\beta$ is exact, thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{S^{11}}\varphi\wedge\mathrm{d}\varphi&=\int_{S^{11}}(\varphi+\beta)\wedge\mathrm{d}(\varphi+\beta)\\
&=2\int_{\mathbb{RP}^{11}}\omega\wedge\mathrm{d}\omega
\end{aligned}
$$
Now it remains to show
$$
\int_{\mathbb{RP}^{11}}\omega\wedge\mathrm{d}\omega\in\mathbb{Z}
$$

I think it must be related to the condition $\int_{S^6}\alpha=1$, but I don't know how to use it. Is there anyone can give me some help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be more direct just to note that $\frac12(\varphi + \rho^*\varphi)$ is $\rho^*$-invariant. It seems to me you need to know a priori why the Hopf invariant is an integer at all. (Certainly you need to specify that the generator $\alpha$ generates the integer cohomology.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Although I know Hopf invariant is an integer, it doesn’t help, since it may be 2*1/2=1, still not even

Comment: How do you know from the differential forms approach that the Hopf invariant is an integer?

Comment: @TedShifrin Of course it's not easy to see it's an integer via approach of differential forms, but it's a fact. However, this fact doesn't help us to solve this problem I think.

Comment: Maybe it suggests that the problem should be done in the framework of integral cohomology altogether? Much as I hate to admit it …

Comment: @TedShifrin I know a proof via steenord operation, but it's quite complicated and it's hard to understand its motivation, so I wonder is there any easier proof, just use $\int_{S^6}\alpha=1$ to conclude it's even.

Comment: As far as I know, you can’t deduce that it’s an integer bare-hands using forms. You need to interpret the integral via Poincaré duality and seeing this as a linking number.

Comment: wait, can you even integrate over a nonorientable space?

Comment: @Snared Sorry? but $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is orientable iff $n$ is odd, thus $\mathbb{RP}^{11}$ is orientable.

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you provide a sketch when you're available? thanks in advance!

Comment: I am confused.  Suppose instead that $f:S^3\rightarrow S^2$ is the Hopf map.  This has Hopf invariant $1$, but so far, it seems to me that your entire argument applies in this case:  $\rho:S^3\rightarrow S^3$ is homotopic to the identity, etc.  What about your argument is special to maps from $S^{11}$ to $S^6$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yeah I know that example, and in fact proof I given here may hold for arbitrary $f\colon S^{2n-1}\to S^n$ when $n$ is even. So we must study more about that integration on $\mathbb{RP}^{11}$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Furthermore, maybe $n=6$ is a quite interesting case, since Adams shows that $f\colon S^{2n-1}\to S^n$ admits Hopf invariant $1$ iff $n=2,4,8$.

Comment: I agree that there must be something fundamentally different about integrating over $\mathbb{R}P^{11}$ compared with  $\mathbb{R}P^k$ for $k\in \{3,7,15\}$.  But it's hard (for me) to imagine what that might be, without already assuming I know about Adam's theorem on Hopf invariant.